# unable to send eth to deployed smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Steezy  { 

    function contractAddress() public view returns (address asd){
        return address(this);
    }
    
    function buy() public payable{
        uint256 listenPrice = 25000000000000000;
        (bool successs, ) = address(this).call{value: listenPrice}("");
        require(successs, "Failed");
    }

}
```

I was trying to send some eth to the deployed smart contract but it gives me Failed execution reverted

Answer (score 1):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Steezy  { 

    function contractAddress() public view returns (address asd){
        return address(this);
    }
    function buy() public payable{
        uint256 listenPrice = 25000000000000000;
        (bool successs, ) = address(this).call{value: listenPrice}("");
        require(successs, "Failed");
    }
    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

You were missing the fallback function try this out. It should work

Comment: Great work like a charm